# настройка AlarmManager для срабатывания в определенное время

Tags: android

Пробую настроить AlarmManager, но ничего не получается. Вот фрагмент кода

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "YOUR TAG");
    //Acquire the lock
    wl.acquire();

    //You can do the processing here.
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    StringBuilder msgStr = new StringBuilder();

    if(extras != null && extras.getBoolean(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE)){
        //Make sure this intent has been sent by the one-time timer button.
        msgStr.append("One time Timer : ");
    }
    Format formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss a");
    msgStr.append(formatter.format(new Date()));

    Toast.makeText(context, msgStr, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Log.d("AlarmManager", "onReceive");
    //Release the lock
    wl.release();
}

public void SetAlarm(Context context)
{
    Log.d("AlarmManager", "SetAlarm");
    AlarmManager am=(AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(ONE_TIME, Boolean.FALSE);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    //After after 5 seconds
    //am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 2 , pi);

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(2015, 10, 26, 11, 58, 00);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
}
```

Comment: Уточните что значит "ничего не получается"

Comment: задаю время в  calendar.set(2015, 10, 26, 11, 58, 00); , но сообщение не появляется?

Comment: И не вызывается в нужное время?.. Проверьте часовой пояс, может в нём проблема. И проверьте вообще работоспособность установив время на системной+30с

Answer (score 3):

Cразу бросается в глаза дата. В Java отсчет месяцев начинается с нуля. То есть октябрь это 9, а не 10. Еще для разных версий API регистрация выглядит по разному:

```
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            } else {
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pi);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Из оф. документации:

> Sets the year, month, day of the month, hour of day, and minute
>   fields. Other fields are not changed; call clear() first if this is
>   not desired. The month value is 0-based, so it may be clearer to use a
>   constant like JANUARY.

А именно:

> The month value is 0-based, so it may be clearer to use a constant
>   like JANUARY.

Что значит, что месяц нужно выставлять в диапазоне `0...11`, а не `1..12`. Итого, октябрь - не 10 месяц, а 9.